# How to deal with nested JSON data in Go

Tags: json, go

This is my first question so every advice is welcome.

Currently, im working on a small little project in Go  that processes stockdata from an API on the web.
I am having a Problem regarding the parsing of some JSON data from there. The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Time Series with Splits and Dividend Events",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-11-13",
        "4. Output Size": "Full size",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (Daily)": {
        "2020-11-13": {
            "1. open": "115.1900",
            "2. high": "117.3700",
            "3. low": "115.0100",
            "4. close": "116.8500",
            "5. adjusted close": "116.8500",
            "6. volume": "4683512",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0"
        },
        "2020-11-12": {
            "1. open": "115.6300",
            "2. high": "116.3700",
            "3. low": "113.4800",
            "4. close": "114.5000",
            "5. adjusted close": "114.5000",
            "6. volume": "6500799",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000",
            "8. split coefficient": "1.0"
        }, ...
```

Im not interested in the metadata, only in the Time Series (Daily) key. Problem is, that this is not an array, but rather a struct containing multiples of structs. I have a struct mirroring the  Fields in the Keys of Time Series (Daily), and want to convert the Time Series (Daily) key into an array of my structs so I can process the data.

I already found some posts that are similar to my issue, but they all have a JSON-Array, which is not present here. I tried doing it myself using Go´s JSON-Library, but with no success.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: This is not valid json.

Comment: Yes, I shortened it since it is a very long json file

Comment: My point is that this is not a JSON file. You have to parse this manually.

Comment: Maybe I chose the example poorly. Here is the complete File: https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=IBM&apikey=demo

Comment: The "..." was inserted by me to show that it is shortened and the original file continues after that point. Have you looked at the link I sent?

Comment: I just checked it. [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) tells me that it is totally fine and syntactically correct JSON. I do not know what your problem is.

Comment: I messed up. This is valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a struct like this:

```
type Daily struct {
   Open string `json:"1. open"`
   ...
}

type Data struct {
   TimeSeries map[string]Daily `json:"Time Series (Daily")`
}
```

Comment: Just tried it out, it worked fine. Thank you very much sir :)